# redirect with htaccess and parameters

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I moved from a `wordpress` to a `typo3` site. On my old sites, the links looked like this:

`http://www.example.org/?page_id=44`

now I want to redirect it to:

`http://www.example.org/contact`

Usually the redirects-rules are no problem, but this time I don't get it why it is not working:

I tried this:

```
Redirect 301 /?page_id=44 http://www.example.org/contact
```

as well as this:

```
RewriteRule http://www.example.org/\?page_id=44 http://www.example.org/contact [R=301,L]
```

and this here:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^example.org/\?page_id=44
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.org/contact [R=301,L]
```

Tried it in several browsers and incognito-mode, but it still remains wrong, it still adds the parameter instead of redirecting to the certain page.

I guess it is somehow doable with `%{query_STRING}` ?

Is it due to the param-thingy? 
Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, got it. It had something to do with the query string:
Final result:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page_id=14$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(index\.php){0,1}$ /kontakt/? [L,R=301,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /\?page_id=44\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /contact? [R=301,L]
```